# Eliminating Soft 404 Errors In GWT When A Page Redirects

Tags: php, google-search-console

We direct visitors on our website to our online digital catalogue by a link to a PHP script which opens in a new browser tab. The script is passed a parameter which identifies the digital document to be opened (eg: /flipper.php?link=catalogue-gbp or /flipper.php?link=catalogue-euro). The parameter is translated into the id of the document (parmlink), which resides on another site. The link is opened using the PHP header command as below:

```
 header('Location: http://edition.pagesuite-professional.co.uk/launch.aspx?'.$parmlink);
```

The problem is, Google Webmaster Tools reports all these pages as Soft 404 errors:

```
 www.oursite.com/flipper.php?link=catalogue-gbp&page=249
```

The script flipper.php does not itself output anything to the browser, it merely serves to translate the parameter into the id of the document and to redirect to it.  How can we avoid these Soft 404 errors?

One solution I thought of is to replace flipper.php by a JQuery script, but I am not sure why GWT thinks this is a 404, as the page exists.

Note: since an optional "page" parameter can be passed to open the document at a specific page, these soft 404 errors keep increasing.

Answer (score 1):

soft 404's really hurt your ranking as they consume your crawl quota. Your best bet is to block them from search engines with a robots.txt disallow directive.
`Disallow: /flipper.php`

Comment: Good thinking Scriptonomy. That would block GWT from crawling links to the catalogues and other digital documents, which to be honest we don't need indexing in Google. Thanks for that. Will make the change today and see if that fixes things. I prefer to have the crawl errors showing "real" errors only.